# regex results are different between C# and regex101

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have created the following regex

```
^xy_yx_blaa_(\d+)([\s\S]*?)(^[A-D]$|QM)+[\s\S]*?(?:SW|Analyzing)
```

And the issue i have is that when i run this is regex101 for an example it will get 199 matches (that is what i want) but when i use it in my C# program it only get 55 matches

After further investigation i found that the C# program only matches the text that contains "QM" only, but in regex101 it matches text that contain A|B|C|D|QM

This is my current code

```
TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor(path);
string text = extractor.ExtractText();
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Thanks in advance

here is a sample of the input string

```
xy_yx_blaa_184

is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically
consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters, between two or more
users of mobile phones, tablets, desktops/laptops, or other devices.
Text messages may be sent over a cellular network, or may also be sent
via an Internet connection.

Derived

QM

SW

xy_yx_blaa_199

is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically
consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters, between two or more
users of mobile phones, tablets, desktops/laptops, or other devices.
Text messages may be sent over a cellular network, or may also be sent
via an Internet connection.

Derived

A

SW
```

in the above text sample the C# will capture the first one ( it contains QM) but in regex 101 it will capture both

Comment: Show the input string.

Comment: Why do you have the not '^' in front of [A-D] as well as the $ after?  It should be ([A-D]|QM)

Comment: @jdweng: `^` isn't a negation here, but an anchor for the start of the line.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte
i added it

Comment: @jdweng 
exactly as Casimir explained

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte
yes it works now :D  Thank you
but could you please explain it in more details because i still don't understand why it's not working in C#

Comment: There can't be two ^ in a regex unless there is an OR.

Comment: @EslamGamal: The newline sequence is `\r\n`: pcre can match `$` at the `\r` position but not the .net regex engine that only succeeds at the `\n` position (or the end of the string). Form  M$ doc: *"`$`  The match must occur at the end of the string or line, or before \n at the end of the string or line. "*

Comment: @jdweng: No you are wrong, you can put any number of `^` in a pattern without using `|`. [Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%5cn%5e.*%5cn%5e.*%5cn%5e.*%5cn&i=xy_yx_blaa_184%0d%0a%0d%0ais+the+act+of+composing+and+sending+electronic+messages%2c+typically%0d%0aconsisting+of+alphabetic+and+numeric+characters%2c+between+two+or+more%0d%0ausers+of+mobile+phones%2c+tablets%2c+desktops%2flaptops%2c+or+other+devices.%0d%0aText+messages+may+be+sent+over+a+cellular+network%2c+or+may+also+be+sent%0d%0avia+an+Internet+connection.%0d%0a%0d%0aDerived%0d%0a%0d%0aQM%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m)

Comment: @EslamGamal See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773520/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You should add an optional `\r?` pattern before any `$` when using `RegexOptions.Multiline` (or its equivalent `(?m)`) due to the fact the files may have Windows CRLF endings and the `$` anchor only matches before `\n`, an LF symbol.

Besides, `[\s\S]` is more of a hack, you need to use `.` and `RegexOptions.Singleline` to match any character.

```
var pattern = @"^xy_yx_blaa_(\d+)(.*?)(^[A-D]\r?$|QM)+.*?(?:SW|Analyzing)";
var results = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Exy_yx_blaa_%28%5Cd%2B%29%28.*%3F%29%28%5E%5BA-D%5D%5Cr%3F%24%7CQM%29%2B.*%3F%28%3F%3ASW%7CAnalyzing%29&i=xy_yx_blaa_184%0D%0A%0D%0Ais%20the%20act%20of%20composing%20and%20sending%20electronic%20messages%2C%20typically%0D%0Aconsisting%20of%20alphabetic%20and%20numeric%20characters%2C%20between%20two%20or%20more%0D%0Ausers%20of%20mobile%20phones%2C%20tablets%2C%20desktops%2Flaptops%2C%20or%20other%20devices.%0D%0AText%20messages%20may%20be%20sent%20over%20a%20cellular%20network%2C%20or%20may%20also%20be%20sent%0D%0Avia%20an%20Internet%20connection.%0D%0A%0D%0ADerived%0D%0A%0D%0AQM%0D%0A%0D%0ASW%0D%0A%0D%0Axy_yx_blaa_199%0D%0A%0D%0Ais%20the%20act%20of%20composing%20and%20sending%20electronic%20messages%2C%20typically%0D%0Aconsisting%20of%20alphabetic%20and%20numeric%20characters%2C%20between%20two%20or%20more%0D%0Ausers%20of%20mobile%20phones%2C%20tablets%2C%20desktops%2Flaptops%2C%20or%20other%20devices.%0D%0AText%20messages%20may%20be%20sent%20over%20a%20cellular%20network%2C%20or%20may%20also%20be%20sent%0D%0Avia%20an%20Internet%20connection.%0D%0A%0D%0ADerived%0D%0A%0D%0AA%0D%0A%0D%0ASW&o=sm) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/L3jBfm).